# How to disable IntelliJ Editor's Code Preview

Tags: intellij-idea, cursive

I'm having hard times trying to disable that "code preview" in the right side of editor, which shows the whole file like a preview. I can't find the name of this feature and also, can't disable. Any clues?

[image: Here's an example]

Comment: There is no such feature in IntelliJ IDEA out of the box; you must have installed a third-party plugin. Check the list of plugins in the settings and turn off the one that provides it.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I've installed IntelliJ and it came enabled somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That feature is provided by a plugin named [CodeGlance](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7275-codeglance).

To disable it ...

- `Preferences > Other Settings > CodeGlance`
- Tick the `Disabled` checkbox

Here's a screenshot showing that ...

[image]